# Find the Jordan canonical form of the matrix

Tags: jordan-normal-form

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$.

My attempt: 
The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $x^{3}=0$.
Now, at $x=0$, the $N(A-xI)=1$, this implies that at least one block of order 1.

$N(A-xI)^{2}=2$, this implies that at least one block of order 2.

the $N(A-xI)^{3}=3$, this implies that at least one block of order 1.

So, the resultant matrix is 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$.

Is this solution is correct?

Comment: minimal polynomial is $x^3$ so the largest block of order $3 \times 3$

Comment: your calculation is correct